# Volume of a polyhedron inside another polyhedron created by joining centers of faces of a cube.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Start with a cube (let us denote it by A). Put a point at the center of its faces and create a polyhedron (denoted by B). Put a point at the center of the faces of this polyhedron and create a second polyhedron (denoted by C) with these new points as vertices.
What is the volume of A if C has a volume of 1?

My Understanding: I can see that a regular octahedron (B) of edge 1/√2 times the edge length of cube A is formed. And then a hexagonal prism C seems to be forming inside B. The volume of B is 1/6 of A but I can't find the relation between B's and C's volume.

Edit: I was incorrect in understanding that C will be a hexagonal prism. It turns out a cube.

Any help would be appreciated. This problem was asked in a Quant Hiring Test.

Follow up: Can a general relation be derived for n such "deep" polyhedrons?

Comment: Polyhedron C is a cube.

Comment: Yeah, I had mistaken it. It is also intuitive for the original polyhedron shape to repeat itself.

Answer (score 3):

Place the large cube in a coordinate system with vertices $(\pm a, \pm a, \pm a)$.  Then the centers of the three faces incident to the vertex $(a,a,a)$ have coordinates $(a,0,0)$, $(0,a,0)$, and $(0,0,a)$, whose centroid is a small cube's vertex $(a/3, a/3, a/3)$.  So the scaling factor is $1/3$ along each axis, hence if the small cube has unit volume, the large cube has volume $3^3 = 27$.

Comment: Thanks, seeing the problem from one octant definitely made it intuitive and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a regular octahedron (which is B), suppose its edge length is $2a$

Then we can align the octahedron, such that its $6$ vertices are

$ P(-a, -a, 0), Q(a, -a, 0), R(a, a, 0), S(-a, a, 0), T(0, 0, \sqrt{2} a ) , U(0, 0, - \sqrt{2} a ) $

Take face $PQT$, its center is

$ V = \dfrac{1}{3} (0, -2 a , \sqrt{2} a ) $

Rotating $V$ about the $z$ axis, we'll generate a square of side length equal to

$ s = \sqrt{2} \left( \dfrac{2 a}{3} \right) $

Now the volume of the octahedron is

$ V_0 = \dfrac{1}{3} ( 8 \sqrt{2} a^3 ) $

Therefore, the cube $C$ volume ratio to that of octahedron $B$ volume is

$ \dfrac{ (16 \sqrt{2} / 27) a^3 }{ (8 \sqrt{2} / 3)  a^3 } =\dfrac{2}{9}  $

Hence, if the volume of $C$ is $1$ then volume of cube $A$ is

$ \text{Volume} = 6 \cdot \dfrac{9}{2} = 27 $